# Using a scope to order by 2 deeply nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i want to order a list of `PickUp` by 2 deeply nested date fields. I have to order by 2 fields because the `latest_eta` is sometimes `null` but is most accurate. If its null I want to fall back on the `scheduled_at` field

Here is my current incorrect scope:

```
  scope :order_by_pickup, -> {
    joins(transit: :pickup)
      .order(TripStop.latest_eta, TripStop.scheduled_at)
  }
```

This does order by `latest_eta` never the `scheduled_at`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is this a TripStop model? If it is a TripStop model, this scope will return TripStop records. In this case, you don't need to join. If this is a PickUp model, join is incorrect. Could you share the entire model class and add some more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [coalesce](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) method. It returns the first non-null argument.

```
scope :order_by_pickup, -> {
  joins(transit: :pickup)
    .order('coalesce(trip_stops.latest_eta, trip_stops.scheduled_at) desc')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with raw SQL

Assuming I got your association correctly:

```rb
  scope :order_by_pickup, -> {
    joins(transit: :pickup)
      .order(Arel.sql('CASE WHEN (latest_eta IS NULL) THEN scheduled_at ELSE latest_eta END'))
  }
```